# Why is callback executing last

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a Javascript class

```
class Secret {

    constructor(secretName) {
        this.region = "us-east-1";
        this.secretName = secretName;
        this.secretString = ''; // initialize secret string
        //this.jsonParseSecret();
    }

    getSecret() {
        let client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
            region: this.region
        });

        var params = { SecretId: this.secretName}

        client.getSecretValue(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else
                console.log(data);           // successful response
                this.secretString = data;
        });
        return this.secretString;
    }
}
```

Then I am attempting call the `getSecret()` method from a test

```
describe('handler', () => {
  test('Test secret.getSecret', async () => {
    var secret = new secrets.Secret("/here/is/my/secret");
    let secretString = secret.getSecret();
    expect(secretString.includes('password')).toBe(true);

  });
});
```

The problem is that the callback function in `client.getSecretValue` is executing after the test call `expect(secretString.includes('password')).toBe(true);`

How can I get the call back to finish before being passed off to the next line of code?

I have tried using await, callbacks, and promises, but I'm definitely not getting it right.

I have tried putting `await` on the `client.getSecretValue()` function with the same results.

Comment: client.getSecretValue is asynchronous function you should wait for that response

Comment: I have tried putting await on the client.getSecretValue() function with the same results. In this specific case how wold I wait for the response other than with `await`?

Comment: ```
function getSecret() {
    //other code
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    client.getSecretValue(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) resolve("");
      else resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I couldn't answer this question. But I provided an example to show you how to use promise.